# | autodesk Forge | export RVT to NWF, NWD, NWC

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

is possible to convert/translate RVT (Revit Format) to NWF, NWD, NWC( Navisworks file formats) using forge engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your comment on my initial answer on 2020-09-16:

You cannot use the [Forge Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/) to translate from RVT to NavisWorks.

Please refer to the list of [supported translations](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/).

For instance, from RVT, you can get DWG, IFC, SVF and thumbnail.

However, all the translations take a CAD seed file format as input.

The output is generally simplified, e.g., SVF (always available, optimised for web viewing) or some other simpler format that can be deduced from the input.

SVF is the end of the line. You cannot translate from SVF back to something more complex and CAD oriented.

The NavisWorks formats are also CAD seed file formats and can be used as input. They cannot be generated as output, though.

Hence, please refer back to my initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can achieve that by using the [Forge Design Automation API for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page).

That provides web-based access to the standard Revit .NET API, which provides the  [Export to NavisWorks method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/1b9538a9-a76b-0a40-2aed-e02f6974a43a.htm).

Here are some recommendations on how to develop and test a Revit add-in locally on the Windows desktop before [migrating it to DA4R](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.55).

Comment: Hello Jeremy I hope you are doing well, I was wondering if this API could achieve my inquiry.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure  
it seems the files should be translated to SVF first and after it can translate it to different formats, please correct me if I am wrong. :)